# On Page Button To Validate HTML

Tags: html, validation

i validate my page using the w3 validation http://validator.w3.org/
while my site is in development i would like a way to validate pages easily. I find myself copy/pasting changing tabs and generically spending roughly 5seconds to validate one page. Is there javascript code i can stick in source and click a validate this link at the bottom of each page? it would make things more pleasant.

Greasemonkey solutions are accepted. I prefer to stay away from non official validations unless they are very stable and known to be good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[WebDeveveloper Toolbar for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60) has a lot of useful tools one of which allow you to validate any web page you are viewing with firefox (remote web pages and even **local web pages!!**)

Answer (score 2):

You can still use the W3C validator. Point a link to this URL — it checks the current page's code.

http://validator.w3.org/check/referer

`<a href="http://validator.w3.org/check/referer">Clean code is happy code</a>`

Comment: +1 but note that my site is in dev and is locally run. visual studios does not allow outside connections (i asked how to allow it before. i cant, need to use a proxy or use iis). So i cant do this until i am almost done and put the code on a server.

Answer (score 1):

there is a firefox extension!!!
web developer ;)
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60